# How to parse a text attribute into a xml atribute in SQL server 2005?

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2005

I have a table which contains an attribute called `custom_fields` that stores a well-formed xml:

```
<Root>
   ...
   <TotalMontoSoles></TotalMontoSoles>
   ...
</Root>
```

But this attribute is not stored as a xml data type, instead it's stored as a text. What I need to do is set the `TotalMontoSoles` value and I was trying to accomplish that by using the modify method from XML-DML but I keep getting a

> *Error SQL: Explicit conversion from data type xml to text is not allowed.*

error when I try to cast the column into a xml type:

```
DECLARE @custom_fields xml
SET @custom_fields = (SELECT CAST(custom_fields as XML) FROM UPLOAD_HEADER_TEMPORAL
@custom_fields.modify('...')
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there any other way I could accomplish this?

UPDATE:

Maybe it's important to point out that what I'm trying to do here is to create a procedure and I'm getting this error during compilation time.

Comment: It looks like your cast to xml is where it is failing.  The error message tells you the problem.  Your Text column can't be magically converted to xml.

Comment: In that case, how should I proceed to discover the issue? I don't think it's not a well formed xml because I've casted that xml outside sql (specifically in Java)

Comment: @NickDeVore Besides, I'm creating a procedure so sql doesn't even know how the xml looks like. It's a compilation time error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text column data types cannot be converted (cast) to XML.  You can (should) use one of the varchar types though.  Microsoft will be removing the text (and image) data type at some point in the future.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

> ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead.

Comment: What I did was casting the column into a varchar first before casting it again to a XML. It appears to be working well.